# login page refresh after succeful login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

i have problem in login page when i try to login and click the submit button the page just refresh and not logging in
Hello dears,
i have problem in login page when i try to login and click the submit button the page just refresh and not logging in
Hello dears,
i have problem in login page when i try to login and click the submit button the page just refresh and not logging in [image]

```
 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuthentication")
               .AddCookie("CookieAuthentication", config =>
               {
                   config.Cookie.Name = "UserLoginCookie"; // Name of cookie   
                     config.LoginPath = "/Login/UserLogin"; // Path for the redirect to user login page  
                 });

            services.AddAuthorization(config =>
            {
                //var userAuthPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
                //config.DefaultPolicy = userAuthPolicyBuilder
                //                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                //                    .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth)
                //                    .Build();
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=ServiceOrders}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

and below are login codes

```
    public LoginModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Email / Username")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var userName = Input.Email;
                if (IsValidEmail(Input.Email))
                {
                    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        userName = user.UserName;
                    }
                }
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
        public bool IsValidEmail(string emailaddress)
        {
            try
            {
                MailAddress m = new MailAddress(emailaddress);

                return true;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please debug sign-in related code and check if it executes as expected. Besides, please check if cookie about `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` is missing on browser.

Comment: on debugging only below method is called
 public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
and keep refreshing

Comment: `on debugging only below method is called public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)` Please share the code of your login form.